# Zend_Validate_GreaterThan ignores equal values

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I have the next validation:

```
$gvGreaterThanPvValidate = new Zend_Validate_GreaterThan(array('min' => 100));
$gvGreaterThanPvValidate->setMessage('GV should be greater than PV or equal');
$gv->addValidator($gvGreaterThanPvValidate);
```

According the Zend documentation it should returns TRUE for value = 100. But for equal value this validator return FALSE. Can you help me? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code from GreaterThan validator. So it return false if the numbers are equals.

```
    if ($this->_min >= $value) {
        $this->_error(self::NOT_GREATER);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

And the doc says : `Returns true if and only if $value is greater than min option` So if the values are equals it returns false

Comment: Yes, sorry. Are you know a validator for equal or greater?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Between validator, that have "inclusive" switch. Just set max to somethng really big like PHP_INT_MAX. It's a hack, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would answer this as I was searching for the same thing and after reading the actual code I note that there is an "inclusive" option, set this to true and you have your GreaterThanOrEqualTo validator:

This is for ZF2:

```
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'bill_total',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'    => [
                ['name' => 'StringTrim']
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name'    => 'greaterThan',
                    'options' => [
                        'min' => 5,
                        'inclusive' => true
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
```